About [PS19]'s Claim of Decryption of LWE is in $\mathsf{NC}_1$
In the paper of Peikert and Shiesian [PS19], they have the following remark (I lined the part I am confused in red below):

However, I am not convinced that decrypting LWE-based encryption is in $\mathsf{NC}_1$ (at least for boolean circuit, but in the constructions their work (See Section 3) considers boolean circuit only, not arithmetic circuit). The reason is as follows:

Suppose $\mathbf{s} \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is the secret key and $\mathsf{ct}=(\mathbf{a},b)$ is the ciphertext. Then decrypting always requires computing the value $b-\mathbf{a}^\top \cdot \mathbf{s} \pmod{q}$. Let $m= \log q$, then the boolean circuit for decrypting requires $mn$ bits as input.
Computing  $b-\mathbf{a}^\top \cdot \mathbf{s} \pmod{q}$ requires $n$ additions modulo $q$. Each addition modulo $q$ is just $m$-bits number addition and thus it requires a circuit of depth $\Omega(\log m)$ to get the result.
Since we have $n$ such additions, it would requires a circuit of depth $\Omega( (\log m) \cdot (\log n))$. The reason is simple: Suppose we have $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$. In the first  steps, we compute in parallel the values $b_i=a_{2i}+a_{2i+1}$ to get $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_{n/2}$. Similarly, we compute in parallel the values $c_i=b_{2i}+b_{2i+1}$ to get $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_{n/4}$. Just like that, we obtain the final value. So we need $Omega(\log n)$ parallel steps, each parallel step requires $\Omega(\log m)$ other parallel steps. So we have the value   $\Omega( (\log m) \cdot (\log n))$.

If the decryption process is in $\mathsf{NC}_1$, then the depth of the boolean circuit must be $O(\log mn)$, not $\Omega( (\log m) \cdot (\log n))$, according to the definition of the class. Am I correct or did I make a mistake somewhere? Thank you very much.
References:
[PS19] https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/nizk-lwe.pdf
